# How is the @altfontfamily variable used in Bootstrap?

Tags: css, variables, twitter-bootstrap

In variables.less, in the typography section there is a variable called `@altfontfamily`.

I want to make use of the Alt Font Family but I don't know how. Is there a class I call to use it? Or is it there to use as a tool for me to make my own class, like this:

```
.serif-link {
        font-family: @altFontFamily;
        }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Less is a system for extending CSS. In this case it allows assigning values for variables and then using them in many places in the css files.

As the header at the top of the file variables.less says:

```
// Variables.less
// Variables to customize the look and feel of Bootstrap
```

Later there is a section saying something like:

```
// Typography
// -------------------------
@baseFontSize:          13px;
@baseFontFamily:        "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
@baseLineHeight:        18px;
@altFontFamily:         Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
```

The baseFontFamily is used in couple places to set the style but I didn't find altFontFamily anywhere. So, I guess it is something reasonable you can use if you want, just as you suggested..